# Accessing https WCF service from other PCs in development / QA environment

Tags: wcf, https

We have created WCF service which is hosted on **IIS** and it is setup to be used with **https**

The https certificate we have generated is **self signed certificate** on one of the PC (lets say PC1), and website is configured to use that certificate.

**We are accessing this WCF service from Windows Service**.

To allow windows service to provide https certificate we have installed that certificate in MMC at **Local Computer store** under **Trusted Root Certification Authority**.

We are also able to call this WCF service if the WCF service and Windows service are configured on same pc.

But when we configure the Window service on another PC (lets say PC2), and try to access the WCF service hosted on PC1's IIS, it is not working.

Please note that we did exported the https certificate from PC1 and imported it to "Trusted Root Certification Authority" of PC2.

Comment: Is the WCF service generally unaccessible from other PCs or only when accessing it from Windows Service? What kind of error/exception do you get?

Comment: Thanks Korli, the WCF was accessible using IP, but not using domain name. We added mapping in Hosts and now we are able to access the WCF service. Please see the details I provided in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we have solved the issue.

The WCF was actually accessible from PC2, in browser when we were accessing it using IP address of PC1. 
However it was not accessible when accessing URL using domain name.

Since our Windows service also access the URL using domain name (as the certificate shows issued by as the domain name of PC1), WCF service was not getting accessed.

We added the IP address of PC1 and mapped it with its domain name in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and we were able to access WCF service of PC1.

Comment: It's great, that you've solved the problem. You can mark your explanation as an answer, to signify that it is a working solution.